# QGIS can a default line style be set for imported tracks

Tags: qgis, symbology

I import .gpx tracks into a project and for that layer

Properties>Symbology>Width is 0.26 mm by default.

Can a default be set, say to 1.25 mm?

Here is what Properties for a newly added track:

[image: Newly added track Symbology Properties]

I would also like the

Properties>Symbology>Label

to be set to 'name'

In response to comment by ahmadhanb, a screenshot of Project Properties

I'm seeing something different in macOS
QGIS version
3.23.0-Master

[image: what is seen in Project Properties]

I've been updating with Brew.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the default line width from the `Project -> Properties -> Styles`. Click `Configure Symbol...` to change the line width from 0.26 to 1.25 mm. However, the default settings are only applied at the project level, not the global level.

[image]

Regarding the default label (default column name), I am not aware of setting a default column name, however, once you set a label for the first GPX layer, then copy and paste the style to other layers and the labels will be applied assuming the column name exists in the other layers.

Comment: I updated the post following your comment. I don't see what you see. Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to click on the pencil icon beside the line symbol? I do not have macOS, but I think you can configure the line from there.

Comment: @ahmadhand. For anything to happen when you click on the pencil icon, a Line has to be selected, for example, "Road" or "simple blue line". And that wouldn't apply to the imported GPX track. I don't see a generic line.  One nice default is when I add another gpx track, a different color is selected, so easier to see one track vs. another track. That line is a "simple line." I'll add to OP